# How to groupingBy into a Map and change the key type

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, partitioning, collectors

I have a code which is suppose to group a list of transaction objects into 2 categories;

```
public class Transaction {
    public String type;
    public Integer amount;
}
```

The following function divided the list into 2 categories by checking a condition. The output map of the stream operation is `Map<Boolean, List<Transaction>>`, but I would like to use a String as its key. So I converted them manually.

```
public static Map<String, List<Transaction>> partitionTransactionArray(List<Transaction> t1) {
    Map<Boolean, List<Transaction>> result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> ((e.type.equals("BUY") || e.type.equals("SELL")) && e.amount < 1000)));

    // I think this is not necessary
    Map<String, List<Transaction>> result1 = new HashMap<>();
    result1.put("APPROVED", result.get(true));
    result1.put("PENDING", result.get(false));

    return result1;
}
```

However, I think there must be a clever way that allows me to do this operation in a single stream operation.

Can some one help?

EDIT:

What if, instead of having a `Map<String, List<Transactions>>` returned, I want to have a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` returned where the List contains only the amount of the transaction.

How can I do it in a single stream operation?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
((e.type.equals("BUY") || e.type.equals("SELL")) && e.amount < 1000)
```

by

```
((e.type.equals("BUY") || e.type.equals("SELL")) && e.amount < 1000) ? "APPROVED" : "PENDING"
```

You should probably use an enum instead of magic string constants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the post and added another question. Can you help?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-

Answer (score 0):

You can use a downstream to `partitioningBy` instead of `groupingBy` using `Collectors.mapping` as:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e ->
                        ((e.type.equals("BUY") || e.type.equals("SELL")) && e.amount < 1000),
                Collectors.mapping(Transaction::getAmount, Collectors.toList())));
```